# Insert no MariaDB dando timeout

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mariadb

Quais são os motivo que levaria o simples insert descrito abaixo demorar tanto que chega a dar timeout no servidor?

```
INSERT INTO wkvmk_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES(904, '_order_key', '')
```

Estrutura da tabela:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Quantidade de registros já gravados: `5729`

Tipo de servidor: `MariaDB`

Versão do servidor: `10.0.24-MariaDB - MariaDB Server`

Versão do protocolo: `10`

Mensagem de erro: `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Fazendo insert diretamente com um client no console (`mariadb-client-10.0`)

Comment: Está utilizando alguma linguagem? a quantidade de insert então é 5729 linhas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta respondendo seus questionamentos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se sua conexão não está com algum processo rodando que pode estar afetando seu banco de dados:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Você pode matar o processo utilizando o comando:

```
KILL [ID_PROCESSO]
```

Uma transação iniciada e que não recebeu um commit pode travar um processo e *matá-lo* como descrito acima resolve!

Comment: Ainda sobre este assunto, estou com o mesmo problema, apenas no update. No insert da tabela funciona, Já conferi meu código e a transação é fechada. Eu entrei no console do mysql, e mesmo no console do mysql dá o erro. A where condition tem apenas uma data e um campo "situacao". O que mais poderia ser?

Comment: A tabela possuí muitos registros? Os campos que você está usando no `WHERE` são indexados?